# Set model to be directed and positioned exactly like the camera position XNA

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, camera

I want to make an fps game. I need the weapon model to be for example 15 `Z` units from the camera and be directed as the same direction the camera points. I've tried litterally everything, and I didnt manage to do it. 
I tried multiply same rotation matrix to both camera and model matricies among other things, and also tried this:

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 200), Vector3.Up);
Gun = Matrix.CreateWorld(gunPos, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);'
gunPos = cameraPos + view.Forward * 15;
```

How can i make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Gun = Matrix.Invert(view);
Gun.Translation += (Gun.Forward * 15); // + (Gun.Down * 4) + (gun.Right * 2);
```

Comment: can you explain what you did?
and why do you add to the `Gun.Translation` shouldnt it be multiplication?

Comment: Line 1 creates a world matrix for the Gun in the exact location and rotation as the camera. Line 2 takes that location (which is the same as `cameraPos` which is already in `Gun.Translation` due to line 1) and moves it forward (in the direction the camera (and Gun) is pointing) 15 units. That forward movement is added (not multiplied) to the current camera location.

Comment: `Gun.Translation=...` is the same as: 
`Gun = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateTranslation(...)` ?

Comment: Kind of... that's OK for the Translation part but `Gun`contains both Translation info and rotation (orientation) info. By starting with `Identity`, you "zero" out the rotation part and make more work for yourself getting it back. When you invert the `View` and call it `Gun`, `Gun` now holds the camera's Translation AND the camera's rotation in world space. From that Translation (the camera's world space position), you then go 15 units in the direction the camera is pointing like this: Matrix.Invert(View).Forward   -Or simply-  Gun.Forward

Comment: Was that helpful? Sometimes it is hard to convey concepts unless both people visualize concepts similarly. If you want to open a chat to clear up any confusion, I'd be happy to do that. I do believe that most confusion is due to incomplete visualizations of key 3d concepts like vectors & matrices.

Comment: that would be great, because i have some other quiestions too, how can we open a chat?

Comment: I set up this chat room for further discussion. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22003/visualizing-linear-algebra-used-in-graphics-programming